# Implementation of Oauth in symfony 4 alongside with Rest api (ionic mobil app)

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm working on a project based on symfony 4, having two sides:

1/ The back office side that used to populating and managing data needed in the mobile app for example :
the mobile app shows Quizzes already entered from the back office (to database), using api.

the back office has its own users that log on to manage data.

2/ The mobil app that communicates using the rest api to get data (from the back office)
mobil users (different from the BO ones) can just log in from the mobil app, their data are stored in database using the api.

the mobil app has different ways of authentification :

- username/password
- Facebook/google (Oauth)

Here comes the confusion, when choosing OAuth, request goes to FB/Google, and ready to be sent through Api,
So how am I supposed to deal with the process of OAuth inside my symfony project ?

Is it right to work this way, or I need to get the authorisation from OAuth providers from my side (from symfony not from the mobil app ) ?

for info :
I'm using :

- LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle as JWT implementation
- Two Guard Authentification systems : one for BO, and one for rest api (jwt)

I hope I had explained well my case.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle if it fits your needs?

Comment: @ThomasBaier , thanks for replying, I read the doc, but I dont know if I have to work with it or no, that's why I'm posting this question to get a bit of glimps about this case. in my project, the open Authentication passes in the mobil side not the front end side, that what confused me.

Comment: So your frontend calls the REST API for authenticating users against the backend? So the real authentication and logic is done in the backend i guess. So HWI Oauth has to also implement in the backend with wrapper logic in the frontend for handling the Oauth url stuff. You send the login request to your backend and let hanlde hwi oauth the authentication. Basically you implement HWIOAuth in your backend and the dialog pages in your frontend.